# max_id only 200 tweets, how to obtain more from one user

Tags: twitter

Could someone please provide me with a sample code that I can use? I want to be able to fetch around 1500 tweets from one user.

Comment: It's not that hard. Just make a sequential api request and at every iteration you should just get the current lowest id and add it to the max_id parameter of the next request.

Comment: How much will you pay us to deliver you completed code?

Comment: I will say thank you ten times as a payment :), and btw thanks for th answers

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by neptune, the solution is to invoke your request multiple times but by adding the `max_id` parameter. The `max_id` value that you specify must be the id of the oldest tweet you received.

At some point Twitter will not return 200 tweets and you will therefore know that you have received all the tweets from that user.

Note that you can get a maximum of 3200 tweets. The oldest ones won't be available via the public Twitter REST API.

Comment: Why did I have a -1? Any reason?